# Java: keyboard shortcut (mnemonic) for a Component

Tags: java, swing, focus, shortcut

I have a `JFrame` and some `JButtons`, `JLabels` and a `JTextfield`.
I need to create a keyboard shortcut so that when it is pressed, the `JTextfield` gets the focus.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Well...what have you tried, and what happened? People will be more likely to help if you've taken some initial steps to try to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I tried to check key event on JFrame , but no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
label.setLabelFor( textField );
```

Otherwise you need to use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: Thanks, key Bindings was the thing i need